# Issue while using elastalert on ES version 7.3.2 when running python command

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastalert

Error running query: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', "[term] query doesn't support multiple fields, found [some_field] and [timestamp_format_expr]")

```
# (Required)
# A list of Elasticsearch filters used for find events

 filter:
 - term:
    some_field: "some_value"
```

Comment: Can you show your query?

Comment: python -m elastalert.elastalert --verbose --rule example_rules/example_frequency.yaml --config config.yaml

Comment: With the yaml config files of course

Comment: The config file is too long,what to do?

Comment: The part of the one where you specify `timestamp_format_expr` and `some_field`

Comment: # (Required)
# A list of Elasticsearch filters used for find events
 filter:
 - term:
    some_field: "some_value"

Comment: Update your question, it's more legible

Comment: May you provide a solution to that?

Comment: What about `timestamp_format_expr`?

Comment: I don't know how and where to specify it.

Comment: Can you [gist](https://gist.github.com/) the whole yaml config?

Comment: Help us help you :-)

Comment: I have done it!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `filter` query correct. This is how you can filter by more field terms:

```
GET <YOUR_INDEX>/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {"term": {"one_field" : "one_value"}},
                {"term": {"another_field" : "another_value"}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```